# How can i throw an illegalargumentexception? I keep getting NullPointerException, but i am supposed to be executing vowels with an error on null

Tags: java, boolean, illegalargumentexception

The code should throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when executing vowels, but I keep getting a `NullPointerException`. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to throw an `IllegalArgumentException`?

```
public class VowelChecker {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(isAllVowels("A test string."));
    }

    public static boolean isAllVowels(String str){
        String temp = str.toLowerCase();
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++){
            char x = temp.charAt(i);
            if (x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u')  {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("characters must be vowels");
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried the code and threw `IllegalArgumentException`, no `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Code seems quite weird... The function name leads us to assume that it is a function used to check if all characters in a string are vowels. We would expect it to return true if all characters are vowels, but instead, it throws an IllegalArgumentException as soon as it detects the first vowel. What is the reasoning behind this?